# Let's describe the Populist badge accurately

Tags: feature-request, badges, populist-badge

As [has been explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood), the Populist badge is actually awarded based on 2x outscoring of an accepted answer that has more than 10 upvotes.  So, can we change the badge text from

> Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x

to

> Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with more than 10 votes by 2x

?

Comment: Either that, or just make it work on an accepted answer with 10 upvotes.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938

Comment: I'm not sure if I should close this - the duplicate I linked to was "resolved" by Jeff because it had to do with a misunderstanding of how the Populist badge worked, but at the same time the same issues you mention here were covered there first.

Comment: I don't thiiiiiink it's a duplicate.  The other question (and its resolved status) seems to be addressing whether the behavior of populist is a bug.  This question is a followup to it, proposing that since it's apparently not a bug, that it be described accurately.

Comment: Description should be fixed. I thought I should get badge here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c), but I have not. Now I'm here. So description is definitely wrong.

Comment: This is actually a `status-completed` now, but I can't add that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Kyle provided a definitive description of the badge, which does differ from yours in a couple of important ways:

> Provided highest scoring answer that
>   outscored an accepted answer with more
>   than 10 votes by more than 2x.

(But IMHO it would be more sensible to change the behaviour of the badge to match the current description, than to keep the current rather counter-intuitive behaviour.)

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but Kyle's text is inaccurate. More than one answer on a question can receive the badge if each of them outscores the accepted answer by 2x. They can't both be the "highest scoring."