# Badge system at SO too slow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, populist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood)

I think there is a flaw in the badge system at StackOverflow.

Recently I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string) that my answer outscored that accepted answer with 10 votes by >2x but I didn't receive the **Populist** badge. Is the badge system too slow or am I missing some rule?

Comment: You got your badge now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer has to get 11 votes (and your answer get >2x that, so at least 23 votes) for you to win the populist badge. This doesn't quite match the description text (see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938) for a bug report about that), which could more accurately read:

> Provided highest scoring answer that
>   outscored an accepted answer with more
>   than 10 votes by more than 2x.

per [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938).

Comment: Ohh! I need just 1 upvote :|

Comment: Ooooh... go on then!

Comment: Ohh not my answer, but the accepted answer needs one more :P

Comment: Did you upvote that answer? thx a lot :)

Comment: @Prasoon - I did (anyone reading, I did read the answer I upvoted before voting - promise!)