# Missing populist badge

Tags: support, populist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938)

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744070/why-should-exceptions-be-used-conservatively/1744176#1744176) currently outscores the accepted answer at 23:11, and has met the criteria for the populist badge for at least two weeks.  (I noticed when the accepted answer hit 10 and waited before asking about it, to make sure it wasn't just the badge job not having run yet.)

Why have I not yet received the badge?  Is there some hidden criteria? (The description only says "Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x".)

Comment: @Downvoter: What was wrong with linking to that answer explicitly?

Comment: It's not the standard; if you want add it again, I only rollback once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not the top answer by votes?! The description is probably not clear enough here.

EDIT:

Acutally a duplicate, see here: [Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938).

Comment: Only one populist badge can be awarded per question.

Comment: I was looking forward to a "real" gold badge too, ah well.