# Populist badge - what does "votes" mean?

Tags: support, badges, populist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood)

I find the description of the **[Populist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist)** confusing. It says:

> Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Does that mean if i have -5 votes and the accepted answer has -11 votes, i get the populist badge too? (-5 outscores the -11 by 2x).

Or does it only count for upvotes, or even the sum of up and downvotes (like displayed left to the answer)?

Comment: Out of your current 1,337 answers (no joke) your lowest scored answer is 0, so I don't think you have anything to worry about. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer must have a minimum of a 10 positive score. You must then get a score twice as high as the  accepted answer (minimum being a positive 20)

Comment: So if the accepted answer has 10 upvotes but 1 downvote so it never reached score 10, i don't get the badge?

Comment: @litb: Yes, the "10 votes" refers to the total net votes displayed on the screen.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken this answer is no longer correct. According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/166973), the score of the accepted answer should be 11 or more, and that of the other answer 23 or more ("more than 2x").