# What's the secret condition for getting the populist badge?

Tags: support, badges, populist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

From the badge page :

> Populist × 713 : Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016806/generating-multidimensional-data/5017268#5017268) with a score of 12 that outscores an accepted answer by more than 2x (accepted answer is 3). But somehow I never got a populist badge. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's read "Answer outscored (an accepted answer with score of more than 10) by more than 2x". The other answer needs a score of more than 10 (i.e. at least 11), and you need to more than double it, so your answer will have a score of at least 11*2+1 = 23.

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> - Provide an answer that meets all of the following criteria:
>
>   - it is the highest scoring answer on the question
>   - it does *not* have the accepted checkmark
>   - it has a score of at least 23
>   - it has more than double the score of the accepted answer
>   - the accepted answer has a score of at least 11
>
> Sources: "Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?", [answer 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6886#6886) and [answer 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938).

Comment: aaah, OK. Thx for the clarification. maybe a rephrasing of that sentence wouldn't be bad...

Comment: Maybe getting rid of that badge wouldn't be bad either. It's just pure luck

Comment: @Kop It's one of those "you got screwed out of your rightful checkmark, but here's a consolation prize" type of things

Comment: @Michael: Not always. My Populist is for an answer which really didn't deserve the upvotes it got -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962396/can-i-do-everything-in-c-that-c-and-c-and-java-can-do/2962405#2962405

Comment: @Billy Well, I just got "Nice Answer" for an answer on a duplicate question, so I say let's take our badges and run

Comment: ROFL (Can't.. stop... laughing...)